# Streaming Comet

Tags: javascript

Привет..
В принципе ясна суть Ajax ,long-polling.

Long-polling

```
function subscribe(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState != 4) return;

    if (this.status == 200) {
      onMessage(this.responseText);
    } else {
      onError(this);
    }

    subscribe(url);
  }
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send('');
}
```

Где можно посмотреть код задания Сomet -streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Концепция `Comet` как раз таки включает в себя и `long-poll` (когда запрос висит в ожидании), бесконечный `iframe` (когда запрос просто висит, и от сервера периодически приходят данные), вебсокеты, polling (когда сервер просто периодически опрашивается).

Comment: бесконечный iframe (когда запрос просто висит, и от сервера периодически приходят данные) это единая реализация ,когда можно заставить серевер висеть постоянно и получать данные когда поступили новые данные?

Comment: @zloctb всё верно. Сервер отправляет <script> тег с данными внутри (прим: <script>parent.handle({какие-то данные});</script>). Браузер принимает, и исполняет функцию handlе с пришедшими аргументами, если грубо говорить.